# Woocommerce product page redirect breaks add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

To be able to add content to the product page I created a page for each product and displayed them with the shortcode `[product_page id="20"]`.

My own product page url is `online-shop.de/my-product-1/`

The product page of woocommerce is `online-shop.de/product/my-product-1/`

So to always keep the user on my editable product page I have a redirect which redirects `/product/my-product-1/` to `/my-product-1/` but my problem now is because of the redirect I can't add the product to the shopping cart anymore. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use the `wp_safe_redirect()` function of wordpress instead of a permanent 303 redirect (with WP Plugin called Redirects). To do this i build the new url by getting the product url and building it again without the "product" directory and use it as parameter in the wp function `wp_safe_redirect($newUrl)`